# SuiteCRM Decimal Symbol reset to username every time user-edit dialog is opened - possibly chrome auto-fill issue

Tags: chromium, suitecrm

I am using SuiteCRM-7.11.18 and PHP 7.3.20.
I have two currencies set up: USD (default) and Swiss Franc, CHF, conversion factor 1.

Everytime I go to User->Profile->Advanced, the field "Decimal Symbol" is reset to my username, resulting in funny Amount values, like

Opportunity Value: 1,000divingtobi00

[image]

When I set the decimal symbol to "." and save, we are good, but the next time I open User->Profile it reappears again, and when I save any change the decimal separator is back to username.

I believe the bug in in the load routine of the edit dialog, because it populates the symbol incorrectly, but I could not (yet) figure out in the code where that happens.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Thanks to @IMSoP's comment I believe this is an issue with the chrome engine auto-fill. Coincidentally my SuiteCRM login name matches my profile login.

The bug does not happen when using InternetExplorer, however both Brave (Version 1.18.77 Chromium: 87.0.4280.101 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and Edge (Version 87.0.664.66 (Official build) (64-bit)) exhibit to the same behavior.

The relevant piece of HTML are the following two cells:
Text field:

```
<td width="17%" scope="row">
<slot>Decimal Symbol:</slot>&nbsp;<img border="0" onclick="return SUGAR.util.showHelpTips(this,'Character used to separate decimal portion' );" src="themes/default/images/helpInline.gif?v=DSEYEbUPxmATH9S4T455VQ" alt="Information" class="inlineHelpTip"></td>
```

and Input field (auto-filled)

```
<td>
<slot>
<input tabindex="14" name="dec_sep" id="default_decimal_seperator" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="." onkeydown="setSigDigits();" onkeyup="setSigDigits();">
</slot>
</td>
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the relevant code; otherwise, it's just a guessing game of where the problem might be, which isn't a good use of anyone's time.

Comment: As a debug tip, though, check that the username is actually in the HTML being rendered; sometimes browser or password manager auto-complete functions fill in the wrong fields.

Comment: Hi @IMSop - thanks a lot, I am investigating along those lines. It really looks like an autofill-issue: I have tried with a blank IE, and it works, i.e. it does not fill in the field. Interestingly, both Brave and Edge do the same thing and fill the field (chrome bug?). I could not yet figure out what triggers it though.

Comment: In that case, the appropriate thing to include in your question is the HTML for that field - probably the field name or something is causing the autofill to think the username should go there.